# Windows 7 Computer Management Not Accessible

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I am having issues trying to access Computer Management from the start menu. The following is a screenshot of exactly how I want to go to computer management. I know that there are other ways to get to computer management, but I would like to go the easier way through the start menu. I tried restarting the computer and I tried patching the computer. No error message comes up or anything. There is no response from the computer when I right click "Computer" and click "Manage" in the start menu.
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: did this happen recently, maybe after installing an application?

Comment: I'm not sure, it isn't my computer, it is a co-workers. I just didn't state that in the question to get right to the point. The problem is fixed though :). Thanks anyways @Serge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIX for Windows 7

This is where you right click on Computer and select manage, and nothing opens, no errors, and CompMgmtLauncher shows up in task manager, but no gui.

may fix other issues also?

modify the registry.

```
HKEY_CLASSESROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\Manage\command
```

change Default data to

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s
```

Requires registry editing skills.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked flawlessly. Thank you very much @Moab! +1 and Accepted.