# Computer Management from context menu of "This PC" is not working on Windows 10 (x86)

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

At first I noticed that I can't access Computer Management using the context menu of "This PC" icon in desktop (nothing happens if I click the "Manage" option in the menu); although I can access it using the search option of taskbar or administrative tools in control panel.

After some research I found out (from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/234481/windows-7-computer-management-not-accessible), although not sure at that time whether it will be effective though) that changing a registry value can be a probable solution for the problem.

So, I opened regedit and there I searched for `CompMgmtLauncher.exe`; found it somewhere like `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\Manage\command` - then changed the value from `%SystemRoot%\System32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe` to `%SystemRoot%\System32\compmgmt.msc /s`.

After that, when I try to access Computer Management using the context menu of "This PC", I get the following error.

[image: Error accessing compmgmt.msc from context menu of This PC]

What can be done at this stage to make Computer Management accessible using the context menu of "This PC"?

P.S- If I manually access `%SystemRoot%\System32\`, then try to run `CompMgmtLauncher.exe` - then nothing happens; but if I run `compmgmt.msc` (which is located in the same location), Computer Management window opens.

Comment: Obviously you should change it back.

Comment: CompMgmtLauncher.exe in a command folder can be found several places in the registry that should be checked, skip muiCache locations.

Comment: %SystemRoot%\System32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe is the default data for each of them.

Comment: @Ramhound : yes, I can change it back - but that is not going to be helpful for me; as the previous registry setting did not work the way it should at the first place.

Comment: Well the parameter you are using is invalid hence the error message you received in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this can stop working is because `CompMgmtLauncher.exe` is launching either **Server Manager** (on Windows Server) or **Computer Management** (on Windows Client), **and it is doing so by launching a shortcut** to the proper tool, which should be located in `FOLDERID_CommonAdminTools` which according to [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb762584(v=vs.85)) is:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
```

You should have `Computer Management.lnk` in there pointing to the appropriate MMC snap-in (or `Server Manager.lnk` on Windows Server) in order for `CompMgmtLauncher.exe` to do anything at all.

If you deleted `Computer Management.lnk` you can either extract it from the `sources\install.wim` file in the Windows ISO image using [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), or manually create it with the following parameters:

**Target:** `%windir%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s`

**Start in:** `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

**Comment:** `Manages disks and provides access to other tools to manage local and remote computers.`

**Icon:** `%windir%\system32\Mycomput.dll`

[image: Icon settings]

Answer (score -1):

Buggy shell extensions can cause such problems, and the excellent ShellExView can be used to narrow down the problem. http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm

Although the page doesn't mention about "Manage" verb blocked by a shell extension, the instructions are worth a try.

Comment: Feel free to explain how the program works and should be used to solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I still had this issue after optimizing Windows 10 LTSB.

Here is the fix:

- Open regedit
- Go to "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\Manage\command"
- Right-click on "command" key -> Permissions -> Advanced
- Change the Owner to your user
- Add your user to "Permission entries" with "Full Control" permissions
- Close Permissions window
- In "command" key modify the "(Default)" string

from: **%SystemRoot%\system32\CompMgmtLauncher.exe**

to: **mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc**

- Close regedit

Answer (score -2):

Actually, most times this Manage- right click problem has nothing to do with the context menu and is caused by the Disk Management snap-in when it hasn't been loaded into the system yet. 
When you right click Manage Win 10 sometimes doesn't load the snap-in & nothing happens.

Why? well I guess Modern coding may be a bit sloppy these days and because of this win 10 is lazy & forgets..

Try Typing this into the Run command: **compmgmt.msc**. *EDIT: I'm just as bad as windows 10 because I previously wrote the wrong run command, but It's the correct one now.*

This command will load the snap-in into windows & the "This PC right click- Manage" should work from now on.

Here is a list of other run commands to get things up & running when they suddenly get Lazy:

```
 azman.msc : Authorization Manager snap-in

 certmgr.msc : Certificate Manager 

 comexp.msc : Component Services Manager

 compmgmt.msc : Computer Management 

 devmgmt.msc : Device Manager

 diskmgmt.msc : Disk Management

 eventvwr.msc : Event Viewer 

 fsmgmt.msc : Shared Folders Management

 gpedit.msc : Local Group Policy Editor 

 lusrmgr.msc : Local Users and Groups 

 NAPCLCFG.MSC : NAP Client Configuration

 perfmon.msc : Reliability and Performance Monitor 

 printmanagement.msc : Print Management

 rsop.msc : Resultant Set of Policy 

 secpol.msc : Local Security Policy 

 services.msc : Services (Snap-in) non-DLL based

 taskschd.msc : Task Scheduler 

 tpm.msc : Trusted Platform Module (TPM) on Local Computer

 WF.msc : Windows Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer

 WmiMgmt.msc : WMI Control (Local)
```